# Is there a way to remove directories along with removing media files in Django?

Tags: python, django

As far as I know, it's quite simple to remove a media file when calling the delete() method. However, I'd like to ask if there's also a way to remove the path that the media file was located.

(wait, is it even a good practice to remove all the empty directories?)

```py
def delete(request, post_pk):
    ...
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_pk)
    post.image.delete()
    # I want to delete the empty directories as well here
    post.delete()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can remove directories using os.rmdir() - https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir

you will need the full path to the directory which you can get using the path stored in settings.MEDIA_ROOT or os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname( "your file here"))

on the second question the directories will be created automatically by the storage module django is configured to use, so there isn't any real difference to remove them